# Pass arguments to Weblogic application

Tags: weblogic

How do I pass arguments to a deployed application in weblogic application server?
-Dmy.var=test for example

Preferably in weblogic application server admin console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into the admin console, and go to: `Environment` > `Servers` > [Your Server] > `Configuration` > `Server Start`, and add the arguments to the `Arguments` field.

Comment: Wouldn't that affect all applications on that specific server then? What if I just want for a specific application?

Comment: Yes, it will affect all applications on that server. I do not know anything specific to a single application. What about making that explicit on your question? I will, then, delete my answer.